# SQL MULTIPLE CASE ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, isnull

I searched through the forum but couldn't find a post to help me, so here goes

I am trying to pull a column of data based on two potential cases, however i cannot get the query to work, I keep getting a syntax error with my > operator:

```
OnHandQty = CASE 
            WHEN job_order_view.job_numb like '5%' THEN isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1) > '0'
            WHEN job_order_view.job_numb like '1%' THEN isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1) > '-1'
            ELSE '-'
        END
```

Comment: What RDBMS and what result are you trying to get? The expression `isnull(thing, 1) > '0'` is a boolean. Some RDBMS will treat that like 0 or 1, but others won't like it syntactically.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  What do you think your case statement will actually do?

Comment: sorry, using SQL Server. I am hoping that the following will happen:

If the criteria for an order is met (which is the like '5%' in my first line), QTY's of greater than 0 will be returned

If the criteria for a job is met (which is the like '1%' in my second line), QTY's of greater than -1 will be returned

Comment: The way you are writing your case statement will not work.  Basically you will end up producing something like `OnHandQty = isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1) > '0'`, which certainly isn't going to work.

Comment: What is the value that you are expecting in OnHandQty from the first two When statements ?

Comment: Your problem is caused by having an equal sign and another comparison operator in the same line.  If the code you posted is part of your select clause, then the > '0' does not make any sense.  If it's part of your where clause, then you can't use an equal sign the way you did.

Comment: Still not totally clear. Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` so we can see the structure, and a sample of data, plus a sample of output?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the expected result I had to enclose the condition inside the IIf() function.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN IIf(1 > 1, 1, 0) END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12334

Using this above it works. If I only leave `1 > 1` I get the same error message.

Edit: Note that this is a standalone example to show how to achieve this. You should be able to adapt it to your code fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said (and I'm still not sure it makes sense), I would do something like:

```
isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1)> CASE 
            WHEN (job_order_view.job_numb like '5%') then ('0')
            WHEN (job_order_view.job_numb like '1%') THEN ('-1')
            ELSE '-'  --What is this part supposed to do?
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
OnHandQty = CASE 
    WHEN job_order_view.job_numb like '5%' AND isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1) > '0' THEN  isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1)
        WHEN job_order_view.job_numb like '1%' AND isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1) > '-1' THEN isnull(q.ONHAND_QTY,1)
        ELSE '-'
    END
```